# Printing some output from R functions and lapply()

Tags: r, function, printing, return

For documentation purposes, my department requires I have copies of the raw output from models, not just the an organized table of the parts I want to keep and publish.

For example, here is a function I wrote to run a CoxPH model and organize the output into a table.  I have several iterations of this function for various outcomes, I use lapply() to call them all.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
    myfun <- function(x){
    model <- summary(coxph(Surv(FAIL, DEAD)~ x + covariate1 + covariate2, data=df))

    # just pull out the parts I need

    results <- data.frame(cbind(model$conf.int[,c("exp(coef)", 
       "lower .95", "upper .95")],                                 
        coef(model)[,"Pr(>|z|)"]))
names(results) <- c("RR", "LL", "UL", "pval")

    # format the the results for the table

results$answer <- paste0(format(round(results[,"RR"],2),2), " (",
                         format(round(results[,"LL"],2),2), ", ",
                         format(round(results[,"UL"],2),2), ")")

    # drop all the results for covariates 

results <-results[substr(row.names(results),1,nchar(expo))==expo,
       c("answer","pval")]
    return(results)
```

The final "results" is just a nice clean data frame of the main independent variable, RR (95% CI) and a p-value, everything runs fine.

When I call the function:

```
    outcomes <- c("DEAD","HEARTDISEASE","LUNGCANCER")
    final.results <- lapply(outcomes, function(x) myfun(x))
```

In this case I get a nice list of three data frames with my organized results.  I can rbind() each element of the list and export it to excel.  -- in truth, there are a lot more outcomes, and age-only model and a fully adjusted model, and several main effect variables, but it all basically works like the code above --

Now, I need to print in the console the original summary() of the Cox model, and still keep my final list of organized output.  I have done this by adding the following to the above code:

```
    myfun <- function(x){

       # all that code listed above #

     # create a list to hold both raw output and my cleaned results
    final <- list()
    final$model <- model
    final$results <- results
    return(final)
```

Then after the function call, I do some separate coding to separate out the summary() portion for each iterative run, print them, then do the same for the final organized results.

Ideally I would just like each iterative run of the function to only return the nice clean table, but print the entire summary(model) to the console.  How can I make that happen in the function that will still work with my lapply() call?

Is there a simpler method than just creating a giant list of everything and dealing with it after all the models are run?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried adding `print(model)` or `print(summary(model))` ?

Comment: I have.  I haven't figured out whether the problem with doing that is due to the function or the lapply() call.  But when I simply add print(model) within the function, there is nothing printed in the console.

Comment: have you tried a `for` loop instead? do you confirm that `myfun("DEAD")` works fine?